# Handlebars.js access nested array values by variable

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a nested object, all indexes are timestamps and it contains information about the **date of the timestamp and events on that day**

```
data : {
    1522620000:  {
        events: {
           1522620940: {title: event1},
           1522620970: {title: event2},
        }
    },
    1522706400:
        events: {
           1522620940: {title: event4},
           1522620970: {title: event6},
        }
    },
    1523311200: {
        events: {}
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I access all events on Friday without looping through the array?
I only have the timestamp `1522706400` represented as the variable `timestamp`  and I would like to access it like `data[timestamp].events`

**Currently I have**

```
{{#each day}} //<-- another variable from a calendar.. don't care about it
    {{# each data[timestamp].events }} //<-- the day contains information about the timestamp but does not contain the events..
        {{ title }}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm usually using **AngularJS** to accomplish things like that but I have a client that wants me to use handlebars instead and I'm really confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by myself. I created the following `Helper`

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getNestedValue", function(obj, options) {
    var context,
        response = "";
    var timestamp = options.hash.key;

    if(typeof obj[timestamp] !== 'undefined'){
        var data = obj[timestamp]; // <-- all information for the timestamp
        $.each(data.events, function (index, item) { // <-- loop through all events
            context = item;
            response += options.fn(context); // <-- include the variable to the template
        });

    }

    return response;
});
```

So I can access it like

```
{{#getNestedValue  ../data key=timestamp }}
    <li class="icon-calendar-events-16">
        <a href="{{ url }}">
            {{ title }}
        </a>
        <small>{{ location }}</small>
    </li>
{{/getNestedValue}}
```